How to display horizontal data into vertical data with MySQL?
I have a MySQL table like the following
prod  price1 price2  price3
----  ----   ----    ----
AA    100    200     400
BB    200    300     655

How to write a query in MySQL so that the table appears vertically like this?
prod   price
----   -----
AA      100
AA      200
AA      400
BB      200
BB      300
BB      655       


This is called "pivoting". https://www.databasestar.com/mysql-pivot/

SELECT prod, price1 AS price FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT prod, price2 AS price FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT prod, price3 AS price FROM your_table
ORDER BY prod;

Replace your table with the actual name of your table. This query will select each product with each of its prices and combine them into a single result set.

You could use UNION ALL to do this:
SELECT prod, price1
FROM your_table
UNION ALL 
SELECT prod, price2
FROM your_table
UNION ALL 
SELECT prod, price3
FROM your_table


Use Cross Join Lateral to transpose columns into rows...
--  S a m p l e   D a t a :
Create Table tbl AS 
( Select 'AA' as prod, 100 as price1,  200 as price2,  400 as price3 Union All
  Select 'BB', 200,  300,  655
);

--  S Q L :
Select   t.prod, x.price
From     tbl t
Cross Join Lateral ( Select price1 Union All 
                     Select price2 Union All 
                     Select price3
                   ) as x(price);

/*  R e s u l t :
prod    price
------  -----
AA        100
AA        200
AA        400
BB        200
BB        300
BB        655    */

OR
If you want to know the origin of price value...
--  S Q L :
Select   t.prod, x.*
From     tbl t
Cross Join Lateral ( Select price1, 'price1' Union All 
                     Select price2, 'price2' Union All 
                     Select price3, 'price3'
                   ) as x(price, origin);

/*  R e s u l t :
prod     price  origin
------  ------  -----------
AA         100  price1
AA         200  price2
AA         400  price3
BB         200  price1
BB         300  price2
BB         655  price3   */

